# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'register') chart.js

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

I just upgraded `chart.js` at v4.1 and `react-chartjs-2` at v5.1, in order to use react 18, in my components library. After I installed my version which includes the updated packages, I get the following error: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'register')`.
Do you have any idea why this is happening? Before the upgrade, everything worked and also, in my components library, I have some examples using Chart components that are working as expected. Thanks!
[ErrorImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txchs.png)
This is my code:

```
import { Chart as BaseChart } from 'react-chartjs-2'
import { Chart as ChartJS } from 'chart.js/auto'
import { CategoryScale, LinearScale, PointElement, LineElement, BarElement } from 'chart.js'

ChartJS.register(CategoryScale, LinearScale, PointElement, LineElement, BarElement)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: https://react-chartjs-2.js.org/#quickstart

Answer (score -1):

It worked after I downgraded to `chart.js` v3.9.1 and `react-chartjs-2` at v4.3.1